# Sign extending bit shifted binary values in C++ using only bitwise operators

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have written the following function which is meant to extract bits 5 through 8 (inclusive) of an integer and return those bits. However, the extracted bits are treated as signed so therefore they must be sign extended after bit shifting.

```
int signedBits5through8(int v){
  int fourBits = (v & 0b111111111) >> 5;
  int signBit = (fourBits & 0b1000) >> 3;
  return (0b11111111111111111111111111110000 * signBit) | fourBits;
}
```

In order to achieve sign extension, my implementation multiplies the sign bit (the most significant bit of the extracted 4 bits, following twos complement conventions) by 28 bits of 1s followed by 4 bits of zeros in order to "sign extend", and then uses an OR mask to apply the last 4 bits. My issue is that I am unable to use any operators other than bitwise ones for this task, and so using the multiplication operator is unacceptable. What's the best work-around in this situation? I also cannot use any conditional or loop logic (if-else, for, etc) in my function.

Comment: `signBit` is either 0 or 1. Why do you multiply with it?

Comment: @273K if it is a 1, it will allow me to add 28 bits of 1s to the 32 bit signed integer I return, making that integer negative. If it is a zero, it will add 28 bits of zeros to the 32 bit signed integer I return, making it positive.

Comment: Shift `fourBits` left so it its sign bit is in bit 32, then shift right back again. You don’t need `signBit` at all. Don’t need the mask either.

Comment: How about extracting 3 bits, and then `if (signBit) return -threeBits;`

Comment: @BoP unary negation is not a bitwise operator.

Comment: Thank you @user207421 , this works perfect. Do you want to make it an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Conditionally negating the least significant bits is not the same thing as sign-extending based on the sign, which of them do you need? They can't both be right.

Comment: @harold What are you talking about? No ‘conditional negation’ here.

Comment: @user207421 I would also like to pretend that BoP's comment doesn't exist, but there it is. But yes I misread OPs reply and thought he replied to BoP which he didn't.

Comment: @harold So you are pretending your comment was directed to bop?

Comment: @user207421 originally it wasn't, I suppose it is now.. not at you in any case, why are we talking about this?

Comment: @Patrick - I might have read the question and missed the title. Didn't see multiplication as bitwise either.  :-)  But anyway, are we sure this is running on a C++ standard and/or hardware where shifting into the sign bit is defined?

Comment: @BoP if this were labeled [tag:c++20] then [two's complement representation would be required by the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#:~:text=all%20C%2B%2B%20compilers%20use%20two%27s%20complement%20representation%2C%20and%20as%20of%20C%2B%2B20%2C%20it%20is%20the%20only%20representation%20allowed%20by%20the%20standard)

Comment: Better to use `return (-16 * signbit) | fourbits;`  -- `-16` ends up being the same value as your bitstring with a 32-bit int and works for other sizes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852598#comment137249203_77852598), you can sign-extend by bit-shifting without using the sign bit explicitly.

Note that before [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) when two's complement representation was not yet required by the standard, this was considered conditionally UB (even though MSVC seems not to think so, which is probably a compiler bug) if the left shift causes signed overflow.

As code, the suggestion looks like this:

```cpp
int signedBits5through8(int v) {
  return (v << 23) >> 28;
}
```

Here are some tests to show it works as intended in all the major compilers, using constant evaluation to ensure that no UB is evaluated (at least with [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) standard enabled): https://godbolt.org/z/6aonbxsbs

```cpp
constexpr int signedBits5through8(int v) {
  return (v << 23) >> 28;
}

static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0000'11111) == +0b0000);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0001'11111) == +0b0001);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0010'11111) == +0b0010);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0011'11111) == +0b0011);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0100'11111) == +0b0100);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0101'11111) == +0b0101);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0110'11111) == +0b0110);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'0111'11111) == +0b0111);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1000'11111) == -0b1000);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1001'11111) == -0b0111);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1010'11111) == -0b0110);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1011'11111) == -0b0101);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1100'11111) == -0b0100);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1101'11111) == -0b0011);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1110'11111) == -0b0010);
static_assert(signedBits5through8(0b11111111111111111111111'1111'11111) == -0b0001);
```

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way of sign-extending under the classical limitations on shifting of signed operands is to flip the sign bit using XOR, then flip it back *using subtraction*. The latter will cause the desired carry propagation to more significant bits.

```c++
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int signedBits5through8 (int v)
{
    const unsigned int all_bits = 0xf;
    const unsigned int sign_bit = 0x8;
    unsigned int uv = (unsigned int)v;
    unsigned int bits = (uv >> 3) & all_bits;
    return (int)((bits ^ sign_bit) - sign_bit);
}

int main (void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        printf ("%3d %3d\n", i, signedBits5through8 (i));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If subtraction is disallowed, that would need to be replaced with emulation, for example:

```c++
int add (int x, int y) 
{
    unsigned int sum, carry;
    carry = x & y;
    sum = x ^ y;
    while (carry) {
        x = carry << 1; // weight of carry bits is twice weight of sum bits
        y = sum;
        carry = x & y;
        sum = x ^ y;
    };
    return (int)sum;
}

int sub (int x, int y)
{
    return add (add (x, ~y), 1);
}
```